# GoLang net/smtp sendMail to recipient with plus signs

Tags: go

I am writing a registration form using GoLang 1.5. I have it all working, but I've noticed if I attempt to sign up using an e-mail with a plus sign in it (someemail+theirlabel@theirdomain.com) I receive the following error:

Transaction failed: Illegal semicolon, not in group

Googling for this hasn't yielded much results, and it seems like Go should handle the plus sign just fine.

```
import (
  "net/smtp"
  "net/mail"
)

func sendEmail(t *Email) bool {
    to := []string{"johndoe+test@gmail.com"}
    err = smtp.SendMail(smtp_url, auth, from_email, to, buff.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        // outputs: Transaction failed: Illegal semicolon, not in group
    }
}
```

I appreciate any advice I get on this.

Thanks!

Comment: That error isn't coming from your code, what is the server you're sending this to?

Comment: It's using AWS SES.

Comment: This isn't a likely problem with Go. Can you make sure your headers are all formatted correctly in the email message?

Comment: Wanted to say thank you for taking the time to support the `+` symbol as it is valid. too many email regex in other languages wrongly discriminate against the `+` symbol.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I tried sending email via SMTP through SES with code pretty much identical to yours. (I used a different email address and defined the other variables as you'd expect.) My guess is that in your real code, you have a semi-colon somewhere (maybe `to` or `from_email` or maybe even one of the headers in `buff`)? If you can make up a dummy email and reproduce with that, perhaps you can share the full details of what input you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error if and only if I had a semi-colon in the `To` header within the message body. E.g.:

```
msg := []byte("To: email1@example.com;email2@example.com\r\nSubject: foo\r\n\r\nbody\r\n")
```

Double-check the `To` header you're sending and make sure it uses commas instead of semi-colons to separate multiple recipients.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to respond, my attention was pulled away from this until now. This was the correct answer.

I was rendering the email template with the html/template package, instead of the text/template package. This was converting the + sign in the e-mail to  unicode &#043; which was resulting in the error. Using the text/template package has corrected this issue. Thanks!